# How to trigger callback with "on_change" on some list variable in Bokeh?

Tags: python, plot, visualization, interactive, bokeh

I am training a neural network that gives me a value of the correctly identified items. Simply put, I have a list ("res") that is being appended by a new integer each 10s.

I want to visualise this in an interactive way using Bokeh, but my callback function doesn't ever get ran. Here is a simple snippet:

```
p = figure()
r = p.line(x=[],y=[], line_width=2)
ds = r.data_source

# this is where I keep my data that are being updated
s = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x= res, y= res))

def callback(attr,old,new):
   global i
   ds.data['x'].append(res[i])
   ds.data['y'].append(res[i])
   ds.trigger('data', ds.data, ds.data)
   i += 1

s.on_change('data',callback)          # run callback if anything changes in s
curdoc().add_root(p)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a bit confusing, you are updating the data in a callback that would only get executed when the data is updated. It seems circular, but more code might help clarify things. Can you come by the public mailing list to discuss? I'd be happy to help with this but the Stack Overflow overlords yell at me when I don't give answers that fit their notion of "answer" (i.e., asking more questions or pointing at our docs), and there's not enough room in comments to discuss anything significant.

Comment: Im not sure how that works but you can reach me on dorajambor@gmail.com. Maybe that's the easiest? @bigreddot

Comment: The public mailing list is best, so that everyone can benefit from the discussion. It's a Google Group, and you can post at https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/bokeh